How to pass complex object to child widget using Flutter Riverpod
Being new to Riverpod, I'm trying to seperate my Data, Logic and Presentation layer.
But I have the following case:
ParentWidget gets List of items async -> ChildWidget takes one item -> Read and Edit in ChildWidget With Riverpod
Code:
class ParentWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final asyncItem = ref.watch(asyncItemProvider);
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          asyncItem.when(
              data: (item) => ChildWidget(item: item),
              error: (err, stack) => Text('Error: $err'),
              loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Item item;

  const ChildWidget({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final itemProv = ref.watch(itemProvider(item));
    final _quantityController =
        TextEditingController(text: '${itemProv.quantity}');
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            'Name: ${itemProv.name}',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _quantityController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Quantity'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ref
                  .read(itemProvider(item).notifier)
                  .setQuantity(_quantityController.text);
            },
            child: const Text('Set Quantitity'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have to pass the data directly to the childWidget and create a new provider in it. And I can't request the data from inside the childWidget, as there are different ParentWidgets from where the data can come from.
Does this violate the separation of the layers? And how could I do it differently?
I tryed searching for examples, that do similar stuff. But these were mostly simple ones, which I couldn't use as template.
